# Level 3 of drop down menu not stretching to width of text

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to figure out why the third level of my drop down menu is not stretching to the width of the text that is contained within it. So far the text just automatically indents to the next line but all the other `li`'s do not do this and are on a single line. Can someone help me find out why this is happening? Thank you!

here is the example I have made so far: http://themedwebdesign.com/salmon/

here is the html

```
   <header>
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div id="logo"><img src="./img/salmon-logo.png" alt=""></div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Meet the Team</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Feature</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Level 3</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Single</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Large</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Medium</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Small</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

and here is the css, I apologize its made using sass. If the compiled css file is needed then I will post it.

```
nav {
    float: right;

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;

        li {
            float: left;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 300;

            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: inherit;
                padding: 15px 25px;
                display: block;
            }

            &:hover {
                color: $colorSite;
            }

            &:hover > ul {
                display: block;
            }
        }

        &:after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: block;
        }

        ul {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            display: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: 1px solid $colorSite;

            li {
                float: none;
                position: relative;

                a {
                    color: $colorDark;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    display: block;
                    padding: 15px 25px;
                    background-color: #fff;

                    &:hover {
                        color: #fff;
                        background-color: $colorSite;
                    }
                }
            }

            ul {
                position: absolute;
                left: 100%;
                top: 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stretch and don't want the 2nd line, you can simply do this in your css

```
header nav ul ul li a { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make `width: 100%;` under css header `nav ul ul ul`

Comment: once I added more text after I added a certain amount the text indented again.

Answer (score 0):

[**`white-space: nowrap;`**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/) will prevent the text from wrapping.

```
header nav ul ul li {
float: none;
position: relative;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: it does stop the text from wrapping but then the text extends outside the `li`

Comment: @zachstarnes you're right.  But that doesn't affect in your case.  I tried in your site too.

Comment: once I removed the `width: 100%` from the `header nav ul ul ul` it worked

Comment: is it better to have it on the `a` or the `li`

Comment: Like what i've suggested in my answer, i would put it in 'a' tag. In this senario i will treat 'li' like a div container and 'a' tag as a text, and i want text to have no-wrap. but works either way tho. it really comes personal choice.